# Find out sunrise time from longitude and latitude

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, time

Is it possible to find out sunrise time for a given Longitude and Latitude value in Objective-C?

Comment: This is more of a "Google" question than a programming question.
Here is a link http://www.earthtools.org/

Comment: Google has a bunch of results on the first page, when you search for 'determining sunrise and sunset'. Here is one of them - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation.

Comment: Sorry people. I was completely unaware of this topic so couldn't judge where to ask. I am glad that I got it sorted out here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some source codes: [Tools and Sources of Sunrise/Sunset Computation](http://personal.inet.fi/cool/jjlammi/stuff.html), including [C](http://personal.inet.fi/cool/jjlammi/rscalc.c) and [C++](http://personal.inet.fi/cool/jjlammi/rscalc_cpp.html) which you can integrate with Objective-C

And [here is a implementation in Objective-C](https://github.com/MosheBerman/KosherCocoa/wiki)!

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Heh, thanks. The code is a port of [a Java Library](http://kosherjava.com), which was designed to keep the hebrew calendar code separate from the sunrise and sunset code. I've actually deprecated the EarthView because the Java library uses an object called "GeoLocation" instead, but it's the same concept.

Answer (score 7):

Try the Sunrise/Sunset Algorithm here:
http://edwilliams.org/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm

Comment: Provided reference is one of the best I have found so far on the net. Simple, clear and complete. Many Thanks.